# How to use Quick-books online Minor-version >= 4

Tags: php, sdk, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have done integration with Quick-Books online using quick-books sdk from this link: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php.

Everything works perfectly except one issue.
The issue is, when I retrieve Items from quick-books, it returns "Non Inventory" items as "service".
I have read different topics which state that I will have to shift to minor version 4 to resolve the issue.
But I can't find a way of how I can make my current SDK to use minor version 4 or above.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have found a workaround, so added the details in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have similar issue, I have found a workaround and sharing it for others to benefit if they want:

open the file `quickbook_sdk\QuickBooks\IPP\Service.php`
Find the following function `protected function _query($Context, $realmID, $query)`

Replace the following code

```
$return = $IPP->IDS($Context, $realmID, null, QuickBooks_IPP_IDS::OPTYPE_QUERY, urlencode($query));
```

With

```
$query = urlencode($query);
$query .= "&minorversion=4";
$return = $IPP->IDS($Context, $realmID, null, QuickBooks_IPP_IDS::OPTYPE_QUERY, $query);
```

**Note:** I was querying Items, so this workaround may only be beneficial in case of getting data through query.

**UPDATE:** 
if you want to add / update items to QuickBooks online with item type NonInventory, You need to modify the following code in your `quickbook_sdk/QuickBooks/IPP.php` file.

Find function named `function _IDS_v3` and inside that function find the following condition

```
 if ($optype == QuickBooks_IPP_IDS::OPTYPE_ADD or $optype == QuickBooks_IPP_IDS::OPTYPE_MOD)    
    {
        $post = true;
        $url = $this->baseURL() . '/company/' . $realm . '/' . strtolower($resource);
        $xml = $xml_or_query;
    }
```

Replace it with

```
if ($optype == QuickBooks_IPP_IDS::OPTYPE_ADD or $optype == QuickBooks_IPP_IDS::OPTYPE_MOD) 
{
    $post = true;
    $url = $this->baseURL() . '/company/' . $realm . '/' . strtolower($resource);
    $xml = $xml_or_query;
    $url .= "?minorversion=4"; // this is the only addition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who use the official php sdk from Intuit, in the root folder you'll find the file `sdk.config`. Edit `<minorVersion>3</minorVersion>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the official PHP SDK:
https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK

You will see that you can use:
$dataService->setMinorVersion("4");
to set the minor version you want to use before making the HTTP call.